# issue regarding layouts in android

Tags: android-layout

I want to know that whether can we split an zml page into 2 parts so then we can use it for 2 activities i.e., upper half for one activity and below half for another purpose.
Is this is possible in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do it but in a sliglty different way:
1. Create an xml for the upper half - one.xml
2. Create another xml for the below half - two.xml
3. To use one.xml and two.xml together, create an xml - three.xml, and include one.xml and two.xml in it using the  tag.
In this way, you can reuse some of your code.

Here is a little hint:

```
<RelativeLayout>
       <include
         layout="@layout/one" />
       <include
         layout="@layout/two" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can also use fragments in this case.

Comment: Yes. You can use Fragments too. But I think it will complicate things a bit, as each Fragment has its own life-cycle.